# Is it possible to have colour variations in Scattered plot in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a Graph with Plot Band and scattered plot. We have a requirement where as the scattered plot circles move away from my plot band it should become of lighter shade and more they are closer to my plot band it should be a darker shade of the same colour. Is it possible to achieve this with highcharts? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible, by formatting each point with a function, you can compare the value of the point to any other point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you help me with a working fiddle for the same? Also, I will be having millions of such scattered plots not sure if formatting each point will affect the performance of my application. If highcharts could provide any inbuilt API to achieve the same then I guess it will be good option.

Comment: You can preprocess your data to include the color shading needed for a certain value greater than some range (your plotBand). There are many ways to do this and it depends on how fine you need to change in colors.

Comment: Please provide the code with your attempts to implement this.

Comment: Is `scattered plot circles` draggable on the chart??

Comment: No its not draggable. But we have click event attached to each point.